# How do I animate drawing a line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to animate the drawing of a simple line from one point within an html element to another. The animation should be slightly slow (maybe taking like one second to reach the second point, but also customizable). I have been searching for the last couple of hours and have yet to find a single javascript library that does this for you. Anyone found or know of anything for this? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://raphaeljs.com/) javascript library. There are also some examples in there

Hope it helps

Comment: This library certainly seems able to draw lines, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to animate the process (i.e. a line slowly being drawn from one point to another). Let me know if it actually can be used as such. Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: I may have been a little hasty with my initial reply. This library may just do the trick. Thanks,
Andrew